# How do I add extra fields (custom captcha) to the registration form in Plone 4.1

Tags: plone

I am trying to add a custom captcha to the registration form for my Plone site. I recently upgraded from 3.1.x to 4.1.3 and this broke my existing customizations to the join_form template and validation script.

I have been trying to follow the [collective.examples.userdata](http://plone.org/products/collective.examples.userdata) example to make my customization. I think I have followed the example correctly but the new field is not being rendered into the registration form.

How do I figure out why the extra fields are not showing up and is there a better way to add a custom captcha to the form?

Note that I did try looking at one of the captcha packages for Plone 4 but the the ones I looked at seemed really complicated (one had parts strewn across 3 packages).

**Update:** Apparently using the stock collective.examples.userdata doesn't work for me either. I add the collective.examples.userdata and I don't get any additional fields on the @@register form.

Also, I am using the old plone 3 fallback template if it makes a difference.

Comment: Could you provide salient parts of code that you wrote so we can see what there's already and what is missing?

Comment: Giacomo Spettoli: See my update about the stock collective.examples.userdata not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example uses the excellent [quintagroup.formlib.captcha](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quintagroup.formlib.captcha) widget, but the general approach can apply to many other situations.

Basically, you do not want to define a captcha field in your user data schema; rather, you want to *temporarily* add it to the form schema when you render the form, in this way:

**browser/interfaces.py**

```
from zope.interface import Interface
from quintagroup.formlib.captcha import Captcha
from my.package import myMessageFactory as _


class IMyRegistrationForm(Interface):
    """Marker interface for my custom registration form
    """


class ICaptchaSchema(Interface):
    captcha = Captcha(
        title=_(u'Verification'),
        description=_(
            u'Type the code from the picture shown below.'
        ),
    )
```

**browser/forms.py**

```
from zope.formlib import form
from plone.app.users.browser.register import RegistrationForm
from quintagroup.formlib.captcha import CaptchaWidget
from my.package.browser.interfaces import IMyRegistrationForm, ICaptchaSchema


class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    """ Subclass the standard registration form
    """

    implements(IMyRegistrationForm)

    @property
    def form_fields(self):
        # Get the fields so we can fiddle with them
        myfields = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).form_fields

        # Add a captcha field to the schema
        myfields += form.Fields(ICaptchaSchema)
        myfields['captcha'].custom_widget = CaptchaWidget

        # Perform any field shuffling here...

        # Return the fiddled fields
        return myfields
```

Finally, register your custom registration form in **browser/configure.zcml**:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    i18n_domain="my.package">

  <browser:page
      name="register"
      for="Products.CMFPlone.Portal.PloneSite"
      class=".forms.MyRegistrationForm"
      permission="zope.Public"
      />  

</configure>
```

Tested using **collective.examples.userdata** and Plone 4.1

Comment: This is closest to what I wanted. Note that I had to add the configuration to collective.examples.userdata/configure.zcml and not browser/configure.zcml to get it to work. It also added the password prompt rather than doing the send a confirm email first (which is what I want).

Comment: Re my last comment, toggling the "Let users select their own passwords" setting on the security tab of @@security-controlpanel does not change things. I assume I'll need to do something else to keep that setting.

Comment: Ahh `myfields = super(RegistrationForm, self).form_fields` should be `myfields = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).form_fields` in browser/forms.py

Comment: I see. I assumed you had forked collective.examples.userdata as your own package, and put the form browser view code in browser/, by convention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the best answer, but it's been discussed at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.zope.plone.user/115264 if you've not already found that.

Comment: Thanks, but that is focused on recaptcha. I specifically don't want to use recaptcha because it is not much better than having no captcha at all. I have a custom one that I used before I upgraded to 4.1 that I would like to adapt to the site. I was thinking that since what I need is an extra date field that I could use a modified collective.examples.userdata but the extra field is not showing up on the register form.