# Plone Captcha didn't work for preventing robot registration

Tags: plone, zope, plone-3.x

Recently the robot registration overwhelms my website, so I add Plone Captcha [using these instructions](http://partecs.com/ploneCaptcha.html) to the `join_form`, but it did not work at all !!

The website still gets spammed with the robot registration for several hundreds of new members every day.

Is there any other way to prevent robot registration?

Comment: what errors you've got? and have you seen http://plone.org/products/plone-captchas and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897730/how-do-i-add-extra-fields-custom-captcha-to-the-registration-form-in-plone-4-1

Comment: I have successfully added plone captcha to my registration form, there's no problem. I meant that after adding captcha the website still gets spammed with the robot registration.

Comment: Oh sorry. please check it: http://spamassassin.apache.org/

Comment: I saw other sites where capcha/recaptcha spam protection was beaten by bots (and I read a couple of article about this). I fear it's a problem of the recaptcha spam protection, not a Plone ones.